# Fresnel equations of S and T waves and Isofrequecy Curves: Feeling confused

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electric-fields, nanoscience

First of all sorry for my (probably) bad english.

I've been studying propagation of light in anisotropic media from the Born and Wolf and from  Landau "electrodynamics in continuous media" and I'm feeling confused about the equations and their meaning.

The Born and Wolf equation of normal surfaces- phase velocity surface- is (2D to simplify):

$$\frac{s^2_x}{(v^2_p-v^2_x)} + \frac{s^2_y}{(v^2_p-v^2_y)}=0$$

Is the 15.2 Chapter 24

The Equation for ray surfaces (ray -energy- surface velocity) is

$$\frac{t^2_x}{(1/v^2_r-1/v^2_x)} + \frac{t^2_y}{(1/v^2_r-1/v^2_y)}=0$$

So, in an uniaxial anisotropic medium (relative permitivity tensor diagonal with one element different from the other two components) the second is an ellipse while the first, in accordance to Born and wolf, is his pedal surface respect to the center, which is something similar but with four lobula.

In an hyperbolic uniaxial medium (with negative, negative and positive components), otherwise, the second is a double fonded hyperbola, while the first is a lemniscata.

I think that everything is correct so far -I expect some feedback with this, I feel that it can be the contrary, the hyperbola is the phase velocity and the lemniscata is the ray energy surface, because obviously the hyperbola take values much higher than $c$ which should be forbidden for energy propagation¿?-.

The interpretation of this surfaces is easy. Choose a direction in the normal surface representation. The Normal Surface gives you the velocity of the PHASE. Now yo make a tangent at that point, and the moment when a perpendicular of this tangent crosses the origin gives you the direction and the velocity of the energy of the ray. And it WORKS because Born & Wolf says exactly the pedal surface thing.

Now, following the born and wolf again I write and calculate (for an uniaxial and non hyperbolic material) the ellipsoid of wave normals and the ellipsoid of ray normals

Ellipsoid of wave normals

$$\frac{D^2_x}{\epsilon_x} + \frac{D^2_y}{\epsilon_y}=C$$

Ellipsoid of ray normals

$$D^2_x*\epsilon_x+ D^2_y*\epsilon_y=C$$

And both are ellipsoids (if they were 3D), and the explanation is that one can choose one direction and then the perpendicular that crosses the ellipsoid is an ellipse with semiaxes indicating the velocity of each polarization -and meaning that two linear polarization waves propagate in the media)

The thing is that one goes to the Landau, directly from Fresnel equations it gets to something similar to the ellipsoids of wave and ray normals (equations 98.2 and 98.4), but Landau call them Fresnel equations. But for uniaxial case both are ellipsoids, and for hyperbolic case both are hyperbolas

So, now the questions:

The Landau 98.2 and 98.4 are the same as the ellipsoid equations? Why the duality hyperbola/lemniscata ellipse/non-named pedal surface of the ellipse dissapears?

In Landau equations it is said that, at one point of the surface it's derivative gives you the value of the other, how is the exact connection?

Generally the textbooks on metamaterials and the papers writes the isosurface in terms of the $k_x, k_y$ etc. in relation with the Born and wolf formula, what exact formula is?

Thank you for reading all this!